# Access DOM elements created by AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns a bunch of html, including some hidden divs with values in as below:

```
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0a1adult">90.7375</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0a1child">90.7375</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0adultPreMargin">265</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0childPreMargin">247</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0adultPostMargin">65</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0childPostMargin">0</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0margin">35</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0partyAdults">2</span>
<span class="hidden" name="price1h1" id="price1h1c0partyChildren">2</span>
```

In my ajax call's success function, i add this html to a div, and then try to call a js function which on clicking of some radio buttons performs some calculations and generates a final price using the above span elements values

The visual stuff all appears, so the call executes, but when the js function tries to access the result using:

```
var partyAdults = $('span#price1h1c0partyAdults').html();
alert(partyAdults);
```

the value is undefined

This all works fine when it is inline in the page, but how can i access the contents of what I have generated?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the function code?

Comment: Using your browsers DOM inspector, have you verified that the `span` elements have been added to the page?

Comment: If the span is hidden will your jquery call to get the html of a hidden span ever return anything, since the span is technically "hidden"? I'm not sure, just wondering. I know you can access an input field that is hidden, but - not entirely sure about a normal html elements innerhtml data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dynamically access DOM elements, you can specify a handler that will be called when the element is ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var partyAdults = $('span#price1h2c0a1adult').live().text();
```

You can use JQuery .live() function to access the dynamically created elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yc2xg/5/)